# Pass a class method (that uses 'this') to another class

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple snippet:

```js
class A {
  constructor(func) {
    func();
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.field = "hello";
    new A(this.printField);
  }

  printField() {
    console.log(this.field);
  }
}

new B();
```

I would expect "hello" to be printed. However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field')

It seems that after passing `printField`, `this` is now referring to `A` instead of `B`. How can I fix it?

**Edit:**
Yes, yes, I know. When copying the snippet I accidentally wrote `new A(printField)` instead of `new A(this.printField)`. The question and the error I get are now fixed.

Comment: The reference error is from using plain `printField` instead of `this.printField`.

Comment: "*ReferenceError: printField is not defined*" means *exactly* what it says: you have no variable defined called `printField`. This is not due to how `this` is handled, although that's *also* a problem in your code. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, yes, I know. When copying the snippet I accidentally wrote `new A(printField)` instead of `new A(this.printField)`. The question and the error I get are now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the context somehow. For example, using an arrow function `() => this.printField()`

```js
class A {
  constructor(func) {
    func();
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.field = "hello";
    new A(() => this.printField());
  }

  printField() {
    console.log(this.field);
  }
}

new B();
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: printField is not defined
> ```
>
> It seems that after passing printField

You **aren't** passing `printField`. The error says that you don't have a variable named `printField`.

To access the property of an object you need to first access the object.

```
new A(this.printField);
```

---

> It seems that after passing printField, this is now referring to A instead of B. How can I fix it?

After you fix the error the message is complaining about, you will get a problem *like* that. (but `this` will point to `window` or be undefined depending on your environment).

That is covered by this duplicate: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).